# Android: OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

i have got ListView of Inbox SMS.I am trying, if i click on any item in the ListView,it will open Sms Manager with filled destination number from recieved sms,but i dont know how i can do it.Can somebody help me?Sorry for my english.

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg, View view, int position,long id) {

                SmsManager m = SmsManager.getDefault();
                Uri uriSMSURIs = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

                int poss = list1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                String pos = String.valueOf(poss);
                Log.d(TAG, "pos: " + pos);

                Cursor cc = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, pos, null, null);

                    String phoneNumber  = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("address"));
                m.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber , null, null , null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the default SMS app with an Intent:

```
   Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("address", "123456789");
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Content of the SMS goes here..."); 
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Yes,but i want if i click on any item in ListView (list of all sms)it will automaticly fill phone number from sms witch i clicked in ListView.

Comment: Work with me here.  I wasn't writing the code for you.  I was giving you an example of how to launch the intent with the extra data parts.  I have not tried what you're trying to do, but I would assume you could replace "123456789" in my example with the phoneNumber you've pulled from your query.

Comment: Bucause i dont know if i can get phone number by this:            Cursor cc = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, pos, null, null);
String phoneNumber  = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("address"));

Comment: What is the value of phoneNumber?  Either use Toast to write it to the screen or Log.d("phoneNumber", "value:'" + phoneNumber + "'");

Comment: The problem is here Cursor cc = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, pos, null, null);          ERROR/SMSManager(840): value: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@43e2b6b8